# Union many tables with different schemas in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

A partner push a table to our BigQuery DW every day, with the following structure (dummy names):

**table names:** entry_2020_06_16, entry_2020_06_17, entry_2020_06_18 ... entry_2022_12_31 
**schema:** col_1, col_2, col_3... , col_??

The important thing here is that the number of columns varies in the daily files. 
In table entry_2020_06_16 it might go from col_1, col_2, ... col_149. 
In table entry_2020_06_17 it might go from col_1, col_2, ... col_23.

I would like to union these files such that no data is lost and missing values are set to null. Furthermore, it needs to be dynamic and should run within the BigQuery environment.

Unfortunately, the "from entry_*" trick does not work as it drops columns not common to all tables.

In the example below, i would like to end up with a table looking like:
columns: col_1, col_2, col_3 
row 1: x, y, z 
row 2: a, b, null

```
create or replace table temp.entry_2020_06_10 as select "x" as col_1, "y" as col_2, "z" as col_3
create or replace table temp.entry_2020_06_11 as select "a" as col_1, "b" as col_2
select * from `temp.entry_20*`
```

Any creative ideas? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS with execute immediate to generate a dynamic query:

```
execute immediate  (SELECT
  string_agg(CONCAT('select ',columns,' from `project-id.dataset-id.',table_name,'`'),'\nUnion all\n')
FROM (
  SELECT
    table_column.table_name,
    STRING_AGG(CASE
        WHEN x.column_name IS NULL THEN CONCAT('null as ',table_column.column_name)
      ELSE
      table_column.column_name
    END
      ,', '
    ORDER BY
      table_column.column_name) columns
  FROM (
    SELECT
      tables.table_name,
      columns.column_name
    FROM (
      SELECT
        DISTINCT column_name
      FROM
        `project-id.dataset-id.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` a where table_name like 'entry_%') columns
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT
        DISTINCT table_name
      FROM
        `project-id.dataset-id.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` b where table_name like 'entry_%') tables
    ON
      (1=1)) table_column
  LEFT JOIN
    `project-id.dataset-id.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` x
  ON
    (x.table_name = table_column.table_name
      AND x.column_name = table_column.column_name)
  GROUP BY
    1 )) ;
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect.
I was not aware of the metadata information in INFORMATION_SCHEMA. And even if I had found that a similar SQL would have caused me lot's of grey hair.

Comment: (Sorry about formatting, I can't seem to format comments). Ahh, forgot a part: I need to save the result to a new table.   

I tried adding the new table definition to the string like this: 
string_agg(CONCAT('create or replace table `project-id.dataset-id.table_name' as select ',columns,' from `project-id.dataset-id.',table_name,'`'),'\nUnion all\n').

But it returns the error: 
"Error: Invalid EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql string `create or replace table temp.a as select..."

Comment: the create or replace statement shsould be on query outside the inner query , so you don't have create table union all create table

Comment: select concat('create or replace table `project-id.dataset-id.table_name` as ',query) from (SELECT
  string_agg(CONCAT('select ',columns,' from `project-id.dataset-id.',table_name,'`'),'\nUnion all\n') query